# Apex DML bulk insert - how to display only list elements that fail DML

Tags: exception

I have a try catch block to handle any problems when inserting a list of users, however, if an exception is encountered, how can I output which user in the list this exception is occurring for? I'm trying to identify this in the debug log. I can only seem to output the exception message itself but I have no way of identify what user in the list the exception occurred for.

CODE:

```
if(portalUsers.size() > 0){
   try{
    insert portalUsers; //Insert list of users
   } catch (System.DmlException e){
    for(Integer k = 0; k < e.getNumDml(); k++){
        System.debug('Portal User DmlException Encountered on Insert: ' + e.getDmlMessage(k));
    }   
   }
}
```

Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below links for SaveResult class.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_dml_insert.htm

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm

Here is the code that I executed in the Developer Console.

This code is trying to insert two users without any mandatory information being populated.

```
List<User> userList = new List<User>();
User usr1 = new User();
User usr2 = new User();
userList.add(usr1);
userList.add(usr2);

Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(userList,false);
for (Database.SaveResult sr : srList) {
    if (sr.isSuccess()) {
        // Operation was successful, so get the ID of the record that was processed
        System.debug('Successfully inserted record. Record ID: ' + sr.getId());
    }
    else {
        // Operation failed, so get all errors                
        for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
            System.debug('The following error has occurred.');                    
            System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
            System.debug('User fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
        }
    }
}
```

And the debug log shows :

```
    04:11:35.077 (77119261)|USER_DEBUG|[16]|DEBUG|The following error has occurred.
04:11:35.077 (77130186)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[16]|System.debug(ANY)
04:11:35.077 (77140071)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[17]
04:11:35.108 (108619368)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[17]|Bytes:12
04:11:35.108 (108715273)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[17]|String.valueOf(Object)
04:11:35.108 (108772014)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[17]|Bytes:22
04:11:35.108 (108800383)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[17]|String.valueOf(Object)
04:11:35.108 (108812589)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[17]|Bytes:2
04:11:35.108 (108848157)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[17]|Bytes:160
04:11:35.108 (108870279)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[17]|Bytes:184
04:11:35.108 (108891551)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[17]|System.debug(ANY)
04:11:35.108 (108901794)|USER_DEBUG|[17]|DEBUG|REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING: Required fields are missing: [Username, LastName, Email, Alias, CommunityNickname, TimeZoneSidKey, LocaleSidKey, EmailEncodingKey, ProfileId, LanguageLocaleKey]
04:11:35.108 (108910963)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[17]|System.debug(ANY)
04:11:35.108 (108922676)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[18]
04:11:35.108 (108932423)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[18]|Bytes:41
04:11:35.108 (108963459)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:44
04:11:35.108 (108998846)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[18]|Bytes:44
04:11:35.109 (109033987)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[18]|String.valueOf(Object)
04:11:35.109 (109072186)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[18]|Bytes:131
04:11:35.109 (109098377)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[18]|String.valueOf(Object)
04:11:35.109 (109117485)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[18]|Bytes:172
04:11:35.109 (109136721)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[18]|System.debug(ANY)
04:11:35.109 (109145242)|USER_DEBUG|[18]|DEBUG|User fields that affected this error: (Username, LastName, Email, Alias, CommunityNickname, TimeZoneSidKey, LocaleSidKey, EmailEncodingKey, ProfileId, LanguageLocaleKey)
```

Comment: Chetan, link-only answers are discouraged on this site. Can you start your answer with a direct and specific answer to the question (perhaps including code) and leave the links for extra information?

Comment: Hi Chetan. Can you add more detail to your answer please? Just linking to two references doesn't work well for our site, specifically because if those two links no longer work (say 6 months from now), this answer will have very little value. Typically, if you want to link to another resource, we encourage it but provide a useful snippet that relates directly to the question for future use.

Comment: Thanks Chetan but I didn't find out anything I didn't already know in those links. My ultimate goal here is to be able to trap the users that don't get inserted and find out why they didn't get inserted. I was hoping to identify these and email the list of them to myself.

Comment: That still doesn't tell me what user the insert failed on. I'm trying to capture at minimum the email address that it fails on. I'm passing a list of users with all the necessary fields to the insert call, and if this bulk insert fails I want to catch what user in the list it is failing on.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ... (assumes you want to allow for partial successes)

```
List<Database.SaveResult> srList = Database.insert(portalUsers,false);
for (Integer i = 0; i < portalUsers.size(); i++) // srList and portalUsers are indexed/ordered equivalently
    if (!srList[i].isSuccess())
       System.debug('Insert failure on row ['+i+'] for user: ' + portalUsers[i].email + 
           'errmsg =' + srList[i].getErrors[0].getMessage());
```

Note that the above displays only the first error encountered for any `portalUser[i]` - if you want to show all, see Chetan's answer.